# Can connect to MySQL db with java but not with PHP?

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have a java application, that can connect to an online MySQL database, like this:

```
private String hostName = "db4free.net:3306";
private String dbName = "mydbname";
private String username = "name";
private String password = "pw";
   try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + hostName + "/" + dbName, username, password);
    System.out.println("Connection established!");
   } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

It works perfectly. However, I try the same with PHP (ignore hostname difference, this should be it):

```
$host = "85.10.205.173"; 
$dbname = "dbname"; 
$username = "name"; 
$password = "pw"; 

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

try 
{ 
    // Open connection with db
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    // Just an error message, if connection fails
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
}
```

And after a while, I get this: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '85.10.205.173' (4)

So why do the two work differently? I think that remote access is enabled (because I could connect with java).

Comment: Why are using hostname in the first and IP in the second?

Comment: The Java one includes a port number - you might need to include that in your PHP code.

Comment: I use an ip, because if I use the hostname in PHP, it doesn't even recognize the host (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'db4free.net:3306' (3)). Same if I include the port.

Comment: Do you have pdo_mysql extension enabled?

Comment: @fortune Of course. This exact code has worked with another database, which was local to the script.

Comment: @RuntimeException Remove $options from your PDO connection string. Try it

Comment: @fortune Well now it doesn't throw the exception, but does nothing.

Comment: @RuntimeException means its connected?

Comment: @fortune No, it "freezes" (loads continuelessly).

Comment: @RuntimeException can you use $host = "85.10.205.173:3306" in your code?

Comment: @fortune  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '85.10.205.173:3306' (3)

Comment: @RuntimeException - you need to pass the port as a separate parameter; your DSN is something like `mysql:host=hostname;port=post`. You could also try to connect to the database server yourself from the command line, using telnet, to make sure that the database server is correct and can be reached from your webserver

Answer (score 0):

Disable the DNS hostname lookups in `mysql`

> To disable DNS host name lookups, start the server with the --skip-name-resolve option. In this case, the server uses only IP addresses and not host names to match connecting hosts to rows in the MySQL grant tables. Only accounts specified in those tables using IP addresses can be used.

Don't forget to restart `MySQL` to take effect.

Not sure this will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I do this on an online PHPmyadmin interface?